# reshape dictionary based on values average and keys combination

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, collections, merge, tuples

I am very new in what dictionaries are concerned. I have a dictionary structured as follows:

```
{'Industrials': ['LUCA', 155], 'Communications': [68], 'Consumer Discretionary': [223], 'Utilities': [18], 'Consumer Staples': [95], 'Unclassifiable': [61], 'Health Care': [100], 'Materials': ['KEVIN', 88], 'Technology': [154], 'Energy': [43], 'Financials': ['ANDREW', 301]}
```

This might sound very 'crazy' but would I be able to redistribute the values so that they are more or less equal. meaning: That the 3 names would be distributed among the remaining keys that have only one value?

Expected output:

```
{'Industrials': ['LUCA', 155], 'Communications': ['LUCA',68], 'Consumer Discretionary': ['LUCA',223], 'Utilities': ['KEVIN',18], 'Consumer Staples': ['ANDREW',95], 'Unclassifiable': ['KEVIN',61], 'Health Care': ['KEVIN',100], 'Materials': ['KEVIN', 88], 'Technology': ['KEVIN',154], 'Energy': ['ANDREW',43], 'Financials': ['ANDREW', 301]}
```

Basically the sum of the total 'second' values in the dictionary is 1306 and these will be split among the current 3 names, without breaking the values.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output? I don't understand what it is that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: edited the desired output. Thanks for the suggestion Aquil